# How many rules can be added to nginx ingress resource

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

*I need to add 1000 rules for ingress path, I am not sure how much rules are allowed in Nginx ingress, could anyone please confirm, How many rules can be added to the Nginx ingress resource*

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: i did not get any limitations details in any documentation so trying to confirm before implemntation